# create plotly table with row headers and input values are a list of rows

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

[image]

I am trying to  make a table like one above in plotly with column headers and row headers. I have the headers as lists x = [a,b,c,d] y =[red,wite,blue] and the values as nested lists of rows z=[[5,8,9,5],[4,4,5,2],[2,5,3,1]].

The code I have for he table:

```
fig_table = go.Table(
        header=dict(
            values=x,
            font=dict(size=10),
            align="left"
        ),
        cells=dict(
            values=z,
            align = "left")
    )
```

The values property expects a list of columns instead of rows so my table comes out inverted. Is there a way to enter a list of rows into values? Also how would I add row headers? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- the structure for the **header** is a 1D list,  structure for **values** is a 2D list which is a transpose of a 2D list you will find in pandas
- have coded both examples of constructing from lists and dataframe

#### create from lists

```
go.Figure(go.Table(
        header=dict(
            values=[""] + list("abcd"),
            font=dict(size=10),
            align="left"
        ),
        cells=dict(
            values=[["red","white","blue"],[5,3,2],[8,4,5],[9,5,3],[5,2,1]],
            align = "left")
    ))
```

#### create from a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    index=["red", "white", "blue"],
    columns=list("abcd"),
    data=np.array([[5, 3, 2], [8, 4, 5], [9, 5, 3], [5, 2, 1]]).T,
)

go.Figure(go.Table(header={"values":df.reset_index().columns, "font":{"size":10}, "align":"left"},
                  cells={"values":df.reset_index().T, "align":"left"}))
```

Comment: The table I have is large (about 50 columns), I just used this one as an example so I was looking for way create a table like one above keeping the inputs x,y and z the same format as shown, and setting x as column header and y as row header. For z would i have to make a function to transpose it to a list of columns?